# Do I need log4j-core when using log4j-core-2.4.1

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, log4j2

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation.
>   Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to
>   the console.

I am using eclipse V4.3.2 in a GWT application.
Both log4j-api-2.4.1.jar and log4j-core-2.4.1.jar are on the class path.

I've seen other postings similar to my error but it's not clear to me what I am doing wrong if anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classpath is not enough (and actually wrong), you need server code within the WAR's `WEB-INF` (`WEB-INF/lib` to be exact here).

Comment: Removed from classpath and the two jars were already in web-inf/lib  - still have same error.  Thanks

Comment: On second try your suggestion worked.  Thank you!  One follow up question where do I place the XML file?

Comment: It should be in the webapp's classloader, so in `WEB-INF/classes` (or in a JAR inside `WEB-INF/lib`). Either that or pass the path to the file as the value of a `log4j.configurationFile` system property (standard Log4j 2 configuration)

Comment: However, every once in a while the config XML file disappears from the WEB-INF/classes folder.  Odd?